# MVC 3, Best way to call this HTML

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Creating a site in MVC 3 and I have this code snippet that I use on several parts on the design. It's a designcode that creates a head for modules on the site. 
Now wondering if this is the best way to call this code snippet? Should i use Helpers or is there a better way?

Today I do like this:

```
    public static IHtmlString FrameModuleHeader(this HtmlHelper helper, int Type, string Headline)
    {
        StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
            html.Append("<div class='module_top'>");
                html.Append("<div class='module_top_left'></div>");
                html.Append("<div class='module_top_middle_" + Type + "'><div class='module_top_headline'><h4>" + Headline + "</h4></div></div>");
                html.Append("<div class='module_top_right'></div>");
            html.Append("</div>");
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(html.ToString());
    }
```

And then call my HTML helpers in the view through:

@Html.FrameModuleHeader(1,"My headline")

Thanks!
/Mike

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would probably use a partial view or a display template that I would include instead of HTML helper because stuffing so much HTML in a C# code looks ugly.

So for example I would have a view model:

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public string Headline { get; set; }
}
```

and a partial:

```
@model AppName.Models.SomeViewModel

<div class="module_top">
    <div class="module_top_left"></div>
    <div class="module_top_middle_@(Model.Type)">
        <div class="module_top_headline">
            <h4>@Model.Headline</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="module_top_right"></div>
</div>
```

and then:

```
@Html.Partial("Foo", new SomeViewModel { Type = 1, Headline = "My headline" })
```

This of course doesn't mean that your HTML helper wouldn't work. It's just that normally HTML helpers should be used to generate small fragments of HTML and in this particular example this doesn't seem to be the case. Also you get HTML intellisense if used in a view which might aid you identify unclosed tags, not properly formatted HTML, ... whereas inside C# everything is one big magic string.

And one final remark about your HTML helper if you decide to use it: Make sure you **HTML encode** this `Headline` string before putting it inside the string builder or you might get bad XSS surprises.

Answer (score 0):

There is really no recommended way. The way that you are doing it is very clean. So I see no reason to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a Partial View. You can put it in /Views/Shared so it is available to everything. One reason this is nice, is it can be more easily edited without having to push out a new code base. If this output never changes, then perhaps that's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You could of course cure the code bloat caused by [divitus](http://csscreator.com/divitis), by removing the unnecessary html tags.

```
public static IHtmlString FrameModuleHeader(this HtmlHelper helper, int Type, string Headline)
{
    StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
        html.Append("<div class='module_top'>");
            html.Append("<h4 class='module_top_middle_" + Type + "'>" + HtmlEncode(Headline) + "</h4>");
        html.Append("</div>");
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(html.ToString());
}
```